# AWS MQTT on OSX

Tags: ios, macos, amazon-web-services, mqtt

In the OSX app [here](https://github.com/ys1382/tel.red), I can use AWS MQTT with iOS9, but when I try the same with OSX10.11, I get this error:

> CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9829)

Error -9828 is defined as

> errSSLPeerCertUnknown     = -9829,    /* unknown certificate */

My OSX info.plist is

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
            <dict>
                    <key>amazonaws.com</key>
                    <dict>
                            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                            <false/>
                            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                            <true/>
                            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                            <string>TLSv1.0</string>
                            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                            <false/>
                            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                            <true/>
                    </dict>
                    <key>amazonaws.com.cn</key>
                    <dict>
                            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                            <false/>
                            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                            <true/>
                            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                            <string>TLSv1.0</string>
                            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                            <false/>
                            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                            <true/>
                    </dict>
            </dict>
    </dict>
```

The p12 (from "openssl pkcs12 -info -in awsiot-identity.p12") is:

```
MAC Iteration 2048
MAC verified OK
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 2048
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 5F 80 DC 6E AB F1 98 6A AA FC 0B 7B 04 F9 0E 66 99 E9 86 4F 
subject=/CN=AWS IoT Certificate
issuer=/OU=Amazon Web Services O=Amazon.com Inc. L=Seattle ST=Washington C=US
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC, Iteration 2048
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 5F 80 DC 6E AB F1 98 6A AA FC 0B 7B 04 F9 0E 66 99 E9 86 4F 
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
```

Why does OSX fail but iOS succeed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of these answers helped. I finally got an answer from Amazon, saying "we don't support OSX MQTT yet." That's not especially useful, and it's frustrating that the key worked on some machines some of the time, but my options now are:

1. wait for Amazon to support OSX MQTT someday maybe
2. use the embedded-C SDK for MQTT

Comment: I've made a very bare-bones port of the iOS SDK AWSCore and AWSIoT frameworks to OS X.  There's a sample app showing how to connect here: https://github.com/bdpdx/AWS-MQTT-IoT-Client-MacOSX

Answer (score 1):

It is failing because of an SSL handshake issue. It is detecting an invalid certificate.

A similar issue was reported and resolved [here](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher/issues/8), referencing the same error code.  That issue was traced to an identity mismatch, due to multiple identities in the p12 file.

In that case, there were two certificates in the p12 files, but the code was only reading the first one.

I suggest dumping the contents of the .p12 file, and confirming the certificates(s). Post them here to review.

Comment: I posted the p12. I don't see two identities in it.

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, I can pay you to help me on this. Contact me via mi sitio web tel punto red

Answer (score 0):

you missing signing CA on your OS X for the certificate, depends on how your created your certificate, you need to import the CA into your keychain. refer [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/managing-device-certs.html)

Answer (score 0):

We have released MQTTBox app on MAC app store recently to create MQTT clients and load test MQTT. You can connect to any MQTT broker available. That may be helpful to you. Please check this [link](http://workswithweb.com) for more details.

NOTE: I am one of the developer of this tool.